# How to logout facebook application website without logout facebook.com

Tags: facebook

I'm using codeigniter, and using javascript sdk / php sdk. But, the logout url generate from getLogoutUrl(), also logout my account at facebook.com.

Any function to clear session only for my website application..?

Comment: Isn't that against the facebook policies ?

Answer (score 3):

You can revoke permissions only for your app.  Check out this page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-logout/

Here is the paraphrased PHP code to accomplish this:

```
$token = $_SESSION["access_token"];

if($token)
{
    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?method=delete&access_token=".$token;
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
}
else
{
    echo("User already logged out.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the very beginning of your website page

```
session_start();

if($_GET['logoutfrmfb']=="logout")
{
   unset($_SESSION['fb_{your app id}_code']);
   unset($_SESSION['fb_{your app id}_access_token']);
   unset($_SESSION['fb_{your app id}_user_id']);
}
```

Find and edit the following lines in src/base_facebook.php (probably lines 506-515)

```
  public function getLogoutUrl($params=array()) {
 return $this->getUrl(
   'www',
   'logout.php',
   array_merge(array(
     'next' => $this->getCurrentUrl().'?logoutfrmfb=logout',
     'access_token' => $this->getAccessToken(),
   ), $params)
   );
  }
```

works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Yes .. I had same issue .. and you can do it simply by doing the following:

In your page log out button or image:

```
<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
```

logout.php ------------------------------------------->

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';     //including the facebook php sdk
$facebook->destroySession();
header( "location:index.php" );
?>
```

when using `facebook=>getLogoutUrl();` <<<<< this makes your facebook.com logout ...

I hope this is what you are looking for :)